# Kinect with OpenNI in VMWare?

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni, ros-hydro, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Hydro with Ubuntu 12.04 through VMWare Fusion in an iMac and I'm trying to get my Kinect (model 1414) to work thourgh OpenNI (I've installed openni-camera, openni-launch, and SensorKinect) but when I try to run `rosrun rviz rviz` or `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color` I get no image feed.

`rostopic list` gives me the normal list of published topics (camera/rgb/image_color, etc) but trying `rostopic hz` only shows "subscribed to [/camera/rgb/image_color]" and nothing else.

I read [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/204518/kinect-no-image-received/) that Kinect won't work well with a virtual machine, but VMWare **is** detecting the Kinect:

```
[ INFO] [1435156294.654805782]: Search for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [ INFO] [1435156294.654805782]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1435156294.908955422]: Opened 'SensorKinect' on bus 1:8 with serial number 'A00365A11201047A'
[ INFO] [1435156295.419182205]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1435156295.420168604]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame'[1435156294.908955422]: Opened 'SensorKinect' on bus 1:8 with serial number 'A00365A11201047A'
[ INFO] [1435156295.419182205]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1435156295.420168604]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame'
```

I also selected that Linux takes the Kinect connection instead of the Mac, so VMWare shows the following connections:

> Microsoft Xbox NUI Audio, Microsoft Xbox NUI Motor, & Microsoft Xbox NUI Camera

Should I give up on VMWare and try a local installation or am I missing something in the Kinect/ROS/OpenNI installation? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212009/kinect-with-openni-in-vmware?/) by [Fancyvase](https://answers.ros.org/users/22908/fancyvase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not saying you should give up on it, but Kinects with VMs (any VM) have been known to not work reliably. You can get them to enumerate, but as soon as you actually want to get any data out of them, things start breaking.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0